# Mathematical modeling Area51 Proposal

Tags: discussion, area51

I wanted to inform those who did not follow that there is a Mathematical modeling proposal in Area 51 under its way:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling

Since it has been always a bit controversial to ask questions on mathematical modeling here, it may be interesting to see the similarities and differences to that proposal.

Comment: At the time of this writing, a large part of the sample questions posted there is extracted from mathoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are new to the SE 2.0 format, proposed sites go through a "Definition" phase where sample questions are posted by interested users to give an idea of what the site will be like. These questions are then voted on, but each person is limited to five votes total.

The current sample questions are taken from mathoverflow and MSE, but this is not necessary. In fact, the new site would best benefit from professional mathematicians in applied areas posting sample questions that they would actually ask each other about mathematical modeling.

Also, if you think the proposed site is silly, leave a comment.